# ¿Como obtener los identificadores de un proceso en Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, línea-de-comandos

Tengo un programa compilado en Linux y ejecutado. Me gustaría obtener todos los identificadores (PID, PPID,UID, EUID, GID, EGID) junto con su prioridad y el estado  del proceso. He obtenido los 3 primeros de esta forma:

```
ps -e -l | grep programaexecutado
```

Pero no se como obtener los restantes. Alguien podría echarme una mano. Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
ps --pid=$(pgrep -f "<nombre de tu programa>") -o pid,ppid,uid,euid,gid,egid,pri,cmd
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ ps --pid=$(pgrep -f "programa_prueba") -o pid,ppid,uid,euid,gid,egid,pri,stat,cmd
  PID  PPID   UID  EUID   GID  EGID PRI STAT
  131     1  1000  1000  1000  1000  19 S    programa_prueba 9999
```

Lo que hace `pgrep` es darte el id del proceso con el nombre "<nombre de tu programa>". El parametro `-f` pide que se busque todo el nombre del programa con el toda la linea de ejecución. Posteriormente, el `id` devuelto del proceso, sera usado como parte del parametro `--pid=<pid>` de `ps`.

Las opciones seguidas de `-o` de `ps` piden los datos que pides las que pides, ademas de `cmd` que es el nombre del comando.

Nota que el comando anterior te trae los *headers*. Si lo que quieres es únicamente la información sin los *headers*, entonces añade un `=` después de cada nombre; es decir:

```
ps --pid=$(pgrep -f "programa_prueba") -o pid=,ppid=,uid=,euid=,gid=,egid=,pri=,stat=,cmd=
```

Para obtener:

```
  131     1  1000  1000  1000  1000  19 S    programa_prueba 9999
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo usted puede utilizar estos comandos que le van a mostrar los detalles.

```
home:~$ ps -f --forest -C sshd 
home:~$ ps -eF
home:~$ pgrep -u user | xargs ps -f -p
```

Espero esto le ayude.